# PDF - How to check a checkbox with FPDF?

Tags: php, fpdf

I am using [FPDF](http://www.fpdf.org/) class to fill a form. I created on adobe acrobat (by retrieving the data from database). I have no problem for text boxes. but I don't know, how it works for check boxes (how to check them).

Here is my php code.

```
<?php 
$req = $bdd->query("my req");

if ($req && $req->rowCount() > 0) {
    $data = $req->fetch();
    require_once "fpdm.php";

    $fields = array(
            'firstname' => $data['firstname'],
            'lastname' => $data['lastname'],
            'mycheckbox' => $data['isAdult'] ? 'Yes' : 'Off'
    );

    $pdf = new FPDM("file.pdf");
    $pdf->Load($fields, true);
    $pdf->Merge();
    $pdf->Output("F", "fileToSave.pdf");
 }
 ?>
```

firstname and lastname fields are filled. but, mycheckbox isn't checked when it has to be checked.

Comment: If you are using the fpdm.php library, it´s simply not supported. It might be easier to try paste a little check mark on top of the checkbox :)

Comment: For adding a checkbox value, I used the ZapfDingbats font which comes packaged with FPDF. [https://webprogramming.ninja/2015/12/28/fpdf-and-the-check-mark/](https://webprogramming.ninja/2015/12/28/fpdf-and-the-check-mark/)

Answer (score 0):

This is not supported in fpdm. You could use this utility : [php-pdftk](https://github.com/mikehaertl/php-pdftk)

Code sample :

```
// Fill form with data array
$pdf = new Pdf('doc.pdf');
$pdf->fillForm([
        'CheckBox1' =>'Yes',
        'RadioButton'=>'Choice1',
        'name'=>'Wizard'
    ])
    ->needAppearances()
    ->saveAs('doc_filled.pdf');
```